# Acessing a Variable inside Jquery Plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.required = function (options) {
        var defaults = {
            controlid: 'none',
            custommessage: 'red',
            itemFunction: function () { },
            isValid: false;
            };
        });
```

this is my jquery plugin (not full code) i want to access isValid out side plugin how can i do this

Answer (score 0):

You are inside a closure, so therefore one can't access the variable from outside. What I'd do would be:

```
(function ($) {
  $.fn.required = function (options) {
    var defaults = $.fn.required.defaults;
  };
  $.fn.required.defaults = {
    controlid: 'none',
    custommessage: 'red',
    itemFunction: function () { },
    isValid: false
  };
});
```

Now one can access the variable like this: `$.fn.required.defaults.isValid`.

Comment: i want to access it from a page

Comment: i want to access it outside plugin

Comment: @Nighil Like I wrote, all you need to do is use `$.fn.required.defaults.isValid` like you would use any other variable.

Comment: @Nighil what Inkbug has said is 100% right. This is how you would access the `isValid` from outside the closure. If you don't understand I suggest doing some reading this was top on google: http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/10/25/understanding-javascript-closures/